# How to exclude string in quotes in my regex?

Tags: php, regex

I want to capture everything except string into quotes, is there a way to do it easily?

The regex is the following one: `\b([\w]+)\b|("([^"])*")`

Here the example with the quotes included:

[image: http://imgur.com/a/MsFNp]

Comment: Judging by your previous question, I suspect you need [`(?|\b(\w+)\b|"([^"]*)")`](https://regex101.com/r/eW9vK5/1). See [PHP demo](http://ideone.com/QHQ6Qt).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PHP` has a nice feature called `*SKIP/*FAIL` (named *backtracking control verbs* as @Federico points out correctly):

```
"[^"]+"(*SKIP)(*FAIL) # everything to the left will be ignored
|                     # or
\b(\w+)\b             # a word surrounded by boundaries
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/jC4tH5/1).

---

In `PHP` this would be:

```
$regex = '~"[^"]+"(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\b(\w+)\b~';
$string = 'this one "but this one not" but again this one';
preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: They are named backtracking control verbs http://www.rexegg.com/backtracking-control-verbs.html

Answer (score 0):

My cooked version:

```
"[^"]*"\s*\K(\w+)|(\w+)
```

[Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gG5mC5/3)